# Using Java, .equalsIgnoreCase doesn't work with two words. How do I fix?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The program works for all variables EXCEPT High Active and Somewhat Active. I can't seem to figure out why but I believe it has to do with the .equalsIgnoreCase

import java.util.Scanner;
public class BMI {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the BMR calculator!");
    System.out.println("Are you male or female? Enter m or f.");
    String gender = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("How tall are you in inches?");
    int height = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How much do you weigh in pounds?");
    int weight = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How old are you in years?");
    int age = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How would you describe your lifestyle? \"Sedentary\", \"Somewhat Active\", \"Active\", or \"Highly Active\"?");
    String active = keyboard.next();
        // This gets all the necessary information to calculate the BMI.

    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) //If the person is female BMR = 655 + (4.3 x weight in pounds) + (4.7 x height in inches) – (4.7 x age in years) 
    {
        if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Sedentary"))
        {
            double BMR = (655 + (4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age)) * 1.2;
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
        }
        ///My issue occurs here I think.
        else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Somewhat Active"))

        {
            double BMR = (655 + (4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age)) * 1.3;
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
        }
        else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Active"))
        {
            double BMR = (655 + (4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age)) * 1.4;
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
        }
        else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Highly Active"))
        {
            double BMR = (655 + (4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age)) * 1.5;
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
        }
    }       
    else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) //If the person is male BMR = 66 + (6.3 x weight in pounds) + (12.9 x height in inches) – (6.8 x age in years)
        {
            if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Sedentary"))
            {
                double BMR = (66 + (6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age)) * 1.2;
                System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
            }
            else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Somewhat Active"))
            {
                double BMR = (66 + (6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age)) * 1.3;
                System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
            }
            else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Active"))
            {
                double BMR = (66 + (6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age)) * 1.4;
                System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
            }
            else if (active.equalsIgnoreCase("Highly Active"))
            {
                double BMR = (66 + (6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age)) * 1.5;
                System.out.println("Your BMR is " +BMR+ " calories!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that there is a problem with String.equalsIgnoreCase, it is as old as the hills.  Double check your input against the hard coded string.  Make sure that it contains the text that you think it does.  Look for extra white space, and the use of a tab instead of a space and visa versa. A debugger, or printing the strings out as ints will help you.

Comment: Why not use numbering for your options, will make life much easier. For example 1 for sedentary and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The `keyboard.next()` is retrieving only the word `Somewhat`. Use `nextLine` instead to retrieve the entire input:

```
int age = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("How would you describe your lifestyle? \"Sedentary\", \"Somewhat Active\", \"Active\", or \"Highly Active\"?");
String active = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: That makes sense. But if I switch it to nextLine() I am not able to input anything when asked about my lifestyle.

Comment: @NiklasHopper For this you need to add an additional `keyboard.nextLine();` after getting the `age` as shown to read the new line that you input after typing the age.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks. I've been trying to solve this all morning.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("How would you describe your lifestyle? \"Sedentary\", \"Somewhat Active\", \"Active\", or \"Highly Active\"?");
    keyboard.skip("\n");
    String active = keyboard.nextLine();
```

this is for you. Not use keyboard.next() for active and skip \n.